# Saving record to rails database from python script

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails

I have Rails application with classic forum models like `Post`, `Topic`.
Then I have python script using `praw` to download certain posts and topics from Reddit. (I know that I can use ruby version, but lets say we have to use this python script)

I'd like to put them directly into my rails database.
I can save them in json format and create rake task to upload them into my database, but I think I don't need to add this complexity and should somehowe save them directly to my rails db from this python script.

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean rails database and what do you mean from python script? Could you describe more?

Comment: What kind of database?

Comment: It's postgres database.

Answer (score 0):

So you can use this one:

```
import psycopg2

db_uri = "dbname='template1' user='dbuser' host='localhost' password='dbpass'"
with psycopg2.connect(db_uri) as conn:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("""SELECT datname from pg_database""")
```